# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () index12312.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I have an error when I deploy on my http:://develop.example.com

When I do the pr to my develop branch to bring new changes to my develop.example.com url when realoding the web page, the entire screen appears blank with the following error

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

After reloading the page again I am back to how I was before.

I don't know what the problem itself is.

I have PWA installed within the website.

This is the error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () index-CR9SSg6k.js:1
```

This is my structure --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6gma.png)
This is my HTML --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LtMQ.png)

More info...
I am deploying to AWS S3

The error is a little more detailed, according to this it tells me that the file is not in
Error Image ---> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f8JW.png)

Add MORE INFO:

VITE CONFIG

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VitePWA({
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      injectRegister: 'inline',
      manifest: false,
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,ico,png,svg}'],
        clientsClaim: true,
        skipWaiting: true,
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5000000
      },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

My npm run build

```
PWA v0.19.5
mode      generateSW
precache  59 entries (1170.53 KiB)
files generated
  dist/sw.js
  dist/workbox-5357ef54.js
warnings
  assets/index-DswbvO1k.js is 6.66 MB, and won't be precached. Configure maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes to change this limit.
```

My error error description
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyOno.png)

Any suggestions?

I need that when I start the page after a deploy it does not leave the screen blank

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of code .... put the relevant code in the question

Comment: Ready, you modify it